# Getting error from ASP.NET MVC 5 on Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise constantly for 'cannot move file to bin Rosalyn'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

I get an error like this:

> Unable to copy file "C:\GitSource\CheckRegister\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.2.1.0\tools\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll" to "bin\roslyn\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll". Access to the path 'bin\roslyn\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll' is denied.    AspNetMVCCheckRegister'

with eight errors that are similar when I am merely updating an API Controller to save a file to a location.  It runs and builds fine when testing with say Fiddler and then I make changes try to build and it blows up.  It is so very very strange as if I kill 'VBCSCompiler.exe' under Task Manager that will fix it.

But that is like blowing up a car to get down a road.  I just am curious how or why this could be happening.  I am using GitHub for a repo and wondering if it's a remnant of an item under source control that should not be.  But I would not think so as most of my bin files are not under source control.

Going in as Administrator doesn't seem to fix it.  It is happening when doing an ASP.NET MVC5 template with Web API or starting from scratch and adding an API.  The version of my VS is 15.3.5.

Comment: Seems to happen mostly when doing rebuild and not build, curious.